# How to update existing Knowledgebase using QnA Maker API v4.0?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I've successfully created my Knowledgebase using [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/operations_getoperationdetails).
But I forgot to add some alternative questions and metadata for one of the pairs.

I've noticed `PATH` method in the API to update the Knowledebase, so updating kb is supported. 
I've created a payload which looked like this:

```
{
"add": {

},
"delete": {

},
"update": {
    "qnaList": [
       {
        "id": 1,
        "answer": "Answer",
        "source": "link_to_source",
        "questions": [
            "Question 1?",
            "Question 2?"
        ],
        "metadata": [
            {
                "name": "oldMetadata",
                "value": "oldMetadata"
            },
            {
                "name": "newlyAddedMetaData",
                "value": "newlyAddedMetaData"
            }
        ]
    }]}
}
```

I get back the following response `HTTP 202 Accepted`:

```
{
"operationState": "NotStarted",
"createdTimestamp": "2018-05-21T07:46:52Z",
"lastActionTimestamp": "2018-05-21T07:46:52Z",
"userId": "user_uuid",
"operationId": "operation_uuid"
}
```

So, looks like it worked. But in reality, this request doesn't take any affect.

When I check operation details, it returns me the following:

```
{
"operationState": "Succeeded",
"createdTimestamp": "2018-05-21T07:46:52Z",
"lastActionTimestamp": "2018-05-21T07:46:54Z",
"resourceLocation": "/knowledgebases/kb_uuid",
"userId": "user_uuid",
"operationId": "operation_uuid"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And how should I update my kb via API properly?

Please help

Comment: Strange thing, it looks like you are using it the right way

Comment: @NicolasR, yeah, this is frustrating

Comment: Can you share the necessary information in order to duplicate your KB in my account and try to do this update on my side? Just to be sure..

Comment: @NicolasR, unfortunetly I cannot do that. It consist of some corporative information.

Did you have something similar in the past or you update your kb without any issues (including metadata)?

Comment: I did not use this update method in the past, only while debugging people questions

Comment: @NicolasR, today I had a conversation with a collegue of mine, he pointed out that I use wrong payload. 

So, it might be a mistake from my side. I will update this question once I figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I discovered that it was necessary to have all the data of the json even if they were not used.
In your case you need "name" and "urls" in the "update" section and "Delete" in "update/qnaList/questions" section:

```
{
  "add": {},
  "delete": {},
  "update": {
  "name": "nameofKbBase", //this
  "qnaList": [
      {
         "id": 2370,
        "answer": "DemoAnswerEdit",
        "source": "CustomSource",
        "questions": {
         "add": [
            "DemoQuestionEdit"
          ],
           "delete": [] //this
        },
        "metadata": { }
      }
     ],
    "urls": [] //this
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was frustrating to face these issues